# Get size of image in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to get size of image. The image is in folder by name encodedImage.jpc

```
a="$(ls -s encodedImage.jpc | cut -d " " -f 1)"
temp="$(( $a*1024 * 8))"
echo "$a"
```

The output is not correct. How to get size? Thank You

Comment: What is the output? What is the expected output? Where is the magic number 5242880 coming from? 1024 and 8 look like magic numbers too, they are just better known over here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Better than parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), the proper way is to use the command `stat` like this :

```
stat -c '%s' file
```

Check

```
man stat | less +/'total size, in bytes'
```

Comment: is it possible to get only 2 or 3 numbers after decimal point.?

Comment: @Tahir, that `stat` command should output an integer. What decimal are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

If by size you mean bytes or pretty bytes can you just use

`ls -lh`

> ```
>  -h      When used with the -l option, use unit suffixes: Byte, Kilobyte, Megabyte, Gigabyte, Terabyte and Petabyte in order to reduce the number of digits to three or less using base 2 for sizes.
> ```

I guess the more complete answer if you're just trying to tear off the file size alone (I added the file name as well you can remove `,$9` to drop it)

`ls -lh | awk '{print $5,$9}'`

Comment: It worked for me but I want to get size in Bytes. It returns size in MB.

Comment: ls is not a tool to be parsed

Comment: You can simply remove -h (pretty print option) to get back to raw bytes

Answer (score 0):

U can use this command

```
du -sh your_file
```